# jquery iterate over child elements

Tags: jquery

I have a `div` with the id `ring-preview`, it has a unspecifed number of `img` elements with the class `stone-preview` inside it.

I would like to iterate over each of these child images and call:

```
$(this).rotate(ring.stones[i].stone_rotation);
```

Where `this` refers the `img` element and `i` refers to its position within the `div`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You're looking for the [`.each()` method](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
For example:

```
$('.ring-preview').children('img').each(function(i) { 
    $(this).rotate(ring.stones[i].stone_rotation);
});
```

If the `<img>` elements aren't direct children, you'll need to call `.find` instead of `.children`.

Answer (score 9):

```
$('#ring-preview img.stone-preview').each(function(idx, itm) {
    $(itm).rotate(stones[idx].stone_rotation);
});
```

Comment: That 'idx' and 'itm' in each function worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

You can use a [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) in these cases, like this:

```
$("#ring-preview img.stone-preview").each(function(i) {
  $(this).rotate(ring.stones[i].stone_rotation);
});
```

The first parameter to the callback function is the index you're after.

Comment: @Lego - missing, evidently :) Fixed!