# list/access elements in embedded html

Tags: jquery, html, loops, embedded-resource, element

I have a HTML page (a.html) which has another HTML page (b.html) loaded into it (in a `div` with ID `pag`). The b.html was loaded using the following code:

```
function load_page(){
   $("#pag").html('<object id="MyPage" type="text/html" data="b.html"></object>');
}
```

I want to list/access the elements on the b.html page from the a.html page.

I did a similar thing on the a.html page, using:

```
function list_elements(){
  elements = "The elements of page a.html are:";

  $(document).find("*").each(function() {
    element = $(this).prop("tagName");
    elements = elements + "\r" + element;
  }); 

  write_elements_on_side_panel(elements);
}
```

The code above works for the a.html page, also displaying the `OBJECT` tagname for the loaded b.html page. However, I don't seem to be able to do the same for the b.html page.

I tried iterating using the `children`, as was described in [jquery iterate over child elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109376/jquery-iterate-over-child-elements)
Unfortunately, when looking at the console, the `MyPage object` containing the b.html page does not seem to have any children.

Is there a way for accessing the HTML elements on the b.html page?

Comment: Any specific reason why you are using an `object` here, and not simply an `iframe`? How to access the elements inside an iframe document should be easy enough to research, I think that has been discussed broadly enough already.

Comment: CBroe, I am actually a Delphi programmer embarking on a new adventure in Javascript. :-) My first research for a way to load the html page led me to using `object`. I will have a look at the possibilities of `iframe` and will get back with the results.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you run the function *before* the embedded page is actually loaded. Keep in mind that the loading function is only executed *after* the main page has loaded and then takes a little while to fetch and save the embedded page.

Instead you have to either listen for some event, like a change event in the DOM, or you have to actively trigger the functions execution after loading the embedded page. An elegant solution would be to listen for a change event and then emit that event when having loaded and saved the page :-)

Comment: Arkascha, For testing purposes I have put both the page loading and the elements listing behind a button, which allows me to control exactly when the functions are executed. Even if I execute the element listing 5 minutes after b.html has completely loaded, it doesn't yield the expected results...

Comment: There seems to be a miss understanding here: your function in its current state does not load an "embedded html page". It creates an object tag inside the parent element. not more. There is no inner html. You certainly can access the `data` attribute holding a url in there. But that url is not somehow automagically loaded if that is what you expect.

Comment: Ok. But the page b.html is actually visible on a.html after the loading. Does this mean that the inner html is never accessible? Any suggestions on how to load the page with complete access to its inner HTML?